# There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There doesn't seem to be a
>   valid compiled storyboard at path

I am getting this error after storing more than 100 row in local database.
Can anybody tell me how should i handle this?

Comment: Have you changed `Targeted Device Family` value to `iphone` or `ipad` only?

Comment: Have you tried after deleting some record?

Comment: yes i tried that as well